# Hoverable and Striped rows on Table via Boostrap 5 not working on my computer

Tags: html, css

as you can see on my screenshot /its from official bootstrap docs/, i cant see Hoverable and Striped rows in Table via Bootstrap5 on my computer. It is happens all of my browsers /edge, brave, chrome/ with or without ads blockers.

What is wrong with my computer?
I have no idea when it started to go wrong like this, but it didn't do it before, because I don't remember that it wouldn't work for me when i programming some website.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

[screenshot as i see Hoverable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0phbw.png)
[screenshot as i see Striped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzVJ3.png)

Comment: Please show us your code and point out what is not working as expected. The 2 screenshots from the official docs look fine, what is not okay for you?

Comment: Because the screenshots look correct and fine, I wonder if the problem you are having is either with your computer screen or with your eyes?  The striping is quite subtle, and if you have any visual impairments it might be preventing you from detecting it.  Or perhaps the contrast or brightness on your computer monitor is preventing you from seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

Alexander, thanks.
I try look at the screenshots at another computer and all  seems ok.
I always look only on live website.
Just adjust some contrast and see everything again.
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).